# Get actual bounds of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple ellipse element:

```
<span style={{
    width: /*someWith*/,
    height: /*someHeight*/,
    borderRadius: "50%"
}}/>
```

and, using `getBoundingClientRect()` I'm getting its bounds (shown in blue).

[image: bounds before rotation]

There is nothing wrong about it as long as I don't rotate it via `transform: rotate`:

[image: bounds after transformation]

now, `getBoundingClientRect()` shows ellipse's "wrong" bounds, showing not the bounds of the rotated ellipse, but it's span element's.

Is there any way to get the actual bounds of the ellipse?

Comment: If there is a solution using SVG instead of a transformed span, feel free to share C:

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect the "correct" bounds should be. The box in red? Or an upright box, but right at the curvature of the ellipse?

Comment: I mean the bounds of the ellipse itself, determined by its curve and not by its span element

Comment: Keep in mind, your ellipse is just a **pseudo ellipse** created by border-radius. So you havn't really changed the geometry of this element - it's still a rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Found a npm package which solved my problem. The only "downside" is that it requires using SVGs rather than HTML element.

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-boundings